# Watir throws InvalidElementStateError when trying to set value to a search text field

Tags: html, ruby, watir

I am a novice to ruby/watir and trying to automate search functionality on a webpage. When I click on the search icon, it opens a dropdown overlay that looks like a modal window, but is really just a div. When I try to set the value for the search criteria, I run into this exception -

Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError: invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.113)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Here's the code that Watir is unable to interact with -

```html
<div class="top-search js-top-search">
  <div class="container">
    <form class="top-search-form" id="search" action="/search" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
      <input id="search_class" name="c" type="hidden" value="users">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <div class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle search_menu" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="la la-caret-down"></span>
            <i class="la" id="selected_search">
              <span>Members</span>
            </i>
          </div>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a class="search-link" data-search="users">
                <i class="la la-user"></i>
                Members
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="search-link" data-search="groups">
                <i class="la la-users"></i>
                Groups
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="q" id="q" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Select a category and search...">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn-default btn header-search-btn" id="go">
            <i class="la la-search"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    <button class="btn close_search_bar js_close_search_bar text-danger">
      <i class="la la-times"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

So far, I've tried the following unsuccessfully -

1. Look up the text field by xpath and then set it's value.
2. Tried to see if the text field is visible - by using xpath, stepping thru each nested block until I get to the text field. Result - Text field isn't visible.
3. Tried @browser.windows.last.use to get on the modal window and then set the value.

Any guidance on this is very much appreciated.

Comment: Any chance the page you are testing is publicly available or you can create a page that reproduces the problem? There could be a number of reasons why it's not visible, which makes it hard to debug.

Comment: It's not publicly available. I haven't had much success with creating a page to reproduce this problem.

Comment: Is there something in the html code I should be looking for? As far as I can tell, there isn't any ajax/javascript code being called.

Comment: What version of Watir are you using? I'm thinking that this might be the issue that got fixed in Watir 6.8.4.

Comment: Also, update to the latest chromedriver. You can use the webdrivers gem if you need to make sure your driver gets automatically updated.

Comment: Definitely have a much older version of Watir. I'll bump it up and the chromedriver and try again.

Comment: I tried recording the test with Selenium IDE and got it to work immediately. I then used suggestions proposed by @JustinKo for how to use the selenium elements with Watir. In short, I could finally access the element by browser.element(:css, "#back_to_top_anchor > div.top-search.js-top-search > div.container > #search > div.input-group > #q").send_keys "Test". Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I am curious. Why does it work with css, but not with div?

Comment: @OrionKe, what do you mean by "but not with div"?

Comment: If I try:     @browser.header(id: "back_to_top_anchor").div(class: "top-search js-top-search").div(class: "container").form(id: "search").div(class: "input-group").text_field(id: "q").set "Test"
 - I get the InvalidElementStateError

Comment: I'm puzzled when you have ID values why you would need to use such complicated and brittle selectors.  Presuming the HTML is valid and the ID values are unique within the page, I should think you would just be able to select the input directly by ID  `browser.element(:css, "#q").send_keys "Test"`  or `browser.text_field(id: "q").set "Test"`

Comment: @OrionKe, I see. Unfortunately, that "div" approach is not equivalent. The "div" approach says find the first header element with matching id, then within that find the first div with matching class, then within that find... etc. If the "first" element isn't the one you want, you get a different result. In contrast, the "css" approach returns the first element that matches the entire chain. Sorry, hard to explain in a comment; I'll try to finish the blog post I started a couple of years ago.

Comment: Thanks @JustinKo for the clarification. I couldn't select by the ID because it turned out the the developer had duplicated the id within the same page for several of the menu options. I reported this as a bug after seeing a response posted by Chuck van der Linden to another issue. Until the issue is fixed, I have modified by code to identify by id and index = 1.